# why reference of a function is being returned as SCALAR

Tags: perl

I am not able to understand if I uncommented  the return line then output will be "CODE" else "SCALAR".. why it is so?

```
use strict;
sub test {
        my ($abc,$grab) = @_;
        print 'i m here';
        print $abc;
        ## return [];   if uncommented then output will be "REF" else "SCALAR"
}

my $pass= "i m good";
my %my_hash = ();
$my_hash{'fun'} = \&test($pass);
print ref($my_hash{'fun'})
```

Comment: You want to get reference to the function but your code actually gets reference to the function's output. This is why the behaviour chages if you change what the function returns. You (probably) want `\&test`  not `\&test($pass)`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Without implicit `return`, a subroutine returns the value of the last expression evaluated. `print` returns 1 on success, i.e. a scalar.

`\&test($pass)` is the same as `\ test($pass)`, i.e. it evaluates to the reference to the value returned by the sub `test`. If it returns 1 from `print`, you'll get SCALAR, if it returns `[]`, you'll get REF, because you have a reference to a reference to an array. You can verify it by dereferencing it, too:

```
print ${ $my_hash{fun} }, ': ', ref $my_hash{fun}, "\n";
```

Comment: ref([]) returns "ARRAY" not "REF"

Comment: @virus: But you're using `\1` and `\[]`, i.e. SCALAR and REF.

Comment: @virus: Please understand the difference between `ref \&test` and `ref \&test()`.

Answer (score 5):

You are not taking a reference to a function.

When you write:

```
\&test($pass);
```

that is a function invocation (you have an argument list).

Therefore, the function `test` is invoked with the argument `$pass` and then you take a reference to the returned value (you should not prefix function invocations with `&` unless you know and specifically desire what it does).

If you want a reference to `test`, you should use

```
$my_hash{'fun'} = \&test; ### (1)
```

If you want a reference to a function that invokes `test` with the currently in scope argument `$pass`, you should use:

```
$my_hash{'fun'} = sub { test($pass) }; ### (2)
```

Note that the latter will create a closure over the currently in scope variable `$pass`. To invoke (1), you use `$my_hash{fun}->($some_arg)`. To invoke (2), you use `$my_hash{fun}->()`.